# Optimize interior color of pivot items

Tags: vba, performance, pivot

Is there a better way to execute this code faster? It's taking forever for 12 months and I'm not sure why. I tried to use variables to define colors, but it's not helping much.

Thanks.

```
Sub Color()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Calendar").PivotFields("Month")
.PivotItems("jan").LabelRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
.PivotItems("jan").DataRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
.PivotItems("feb").LabelRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
.PivotItems("feb").DataRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. It only took a few seconds.

```
Sub Color_two()
Dim Color(12)
    Color(1) = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Color(2) = RGB(255, 153, 0)
    Color(3) = RGB(255, 153, 0)
    Color(4) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Color(5) = RGB(255, 0, 255)
    Color(6) = RGB(102, 0, 204)
    Color(7) = RGB(51, 0, 255)
    Color(8) = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    Color(9) = RGB(51, 102, 102)
    Color(10) = RGB(153, 255, 0)
    Color(11) = RGB(153, 153, 153)
    Color(12) = RGB(153, 255, 0)
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Calendar")
    For i = 1 To 12
        Mmonth= "'" & i & "'"
        .PivotSelect "Month[" & Mmonth & "]", xlDataAndLabel, True
        Selection.Interior.Color = Color(i)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and then back to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

This will prevent your pivot table from refreshing every time you do something to it. I think it's strange if it's refreshing just because you are monkeying with the color, but it's excel and excel can be strange.

```
Sub Color()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Calendar").PivotFields("Month")
    .PivotItems("jan").LabelRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .PivotItems("jan").DataRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .PivotItems("feb").LabelRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
    .PivotItems("feb").DataRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
  End With

  'Force a calc before toggling calculation back on
  Application.Calculate
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You may also want to toggle off `Application.EnableEvents` too while it's running just to cover your bases. This will prevent any other code in the sheet being triggered by an event from firing. Like `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or what have you.

Comment: I tried to run your code for 6 months, however it still took 5 minutes to finish.